# How can I add my pass before X86 AT&T-Style Assembly Printer pass?

Tags: llvm, llvm-3.0, llvm-c++-api

How can I add my pass before X86 AT&T-Style Assembly Printer pass?
I need to change MachineFunction and save changes to the asm file.
The problem is that my pass is triggered after all.

Pass debug:

- 0x202a430      Freeing Pass 'Execution dependency fix' on Function
  'InterlockedBitTestAndSet'... 0x202a430     Executing Pass 'X86
  AT&T-Style Assembly Printer' on Function
  'InterlockedBitTestAndSet'... 0x2094f80       Required Analyses:
  Uninitialized Pass, Machine Module Information, Create Garbage
  Collector Module Metadata

  -*- 'X86 AT&T-Style Assembly Printer' is the last user of following
  pass instances. Free these instances 0x202a430      Freeing Pass 'X86
  AT&T-Style Assembly Printer' on Function
  'InterlockedBitTestAndSet'... 0x202a430     Executing Pass 'Delete
  Garbage Collector Information' on Function
  'InterlockedBitTestAndSet'... 0x2095268       Required Analyses:
  Create Garbage Collector Module Metadata

  -*- 'Delete Garbage Collector Information' is the last user of
  following pass instances. Free these instances 0x202a430      Freeing
  Pass 'Delete Garbage Collector Information' on Function
  'InterlockedBitTestAndSet'... 0x202a430     Executing Pass 'Simple
  Register Allocator' on Function 'InterlockedBitTestAndSet'...
  0x20955b8       Required Analyses: Uninitialized Pass

full source:
http://www1.datafilehost.com/d/7f544b4b

Comment: No one has any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `LLVMTargetMachine::addPassesToEmitFile` which is implemented in LLVMTargetMachine.cpp.

That can be a reasonable place to add any pass you want to run before the AsmPrinter pass is invoked.